# Can not imorpt modules from 'utils' error

Tags: python, import, module

I am trying to do some NLP on jupyter notebook, while modules cannot be imported from `utils`. Though `utils` was downloaded again by `pip install utils` in cmd. The problem still existed. Can anyone help me out? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please don't use images for information that is easily communicated in text. Images are not friendly to search or copy & paste or visually impaired people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with `cosine_similarity`

there is no such module or function.

import cosine similarity with:

```
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I opened the ' _init_.py' file of 'utils' , which is empty. Does that means there is no module that can be imported from 'utils' ?

Comment: no __init__.py just indicates that it is a package/module